# Validating form and url variables in coldfusion

Tags: validation, url, coldfusion

I have a question about validating form and url variables in coldfusion. For example I have a url that looks like, https://dev.abc.com/test.cfm?page_id=4&id=54658, however I updated the url to look something like:  https://dev.abc.com/test.cfm?page_id=4&id=546589687534, in this case the page errors out and I get a "Invalid data 23254523456 for CFSQLTYPE CF_SQL_INTEGER" on the cfc call. How do I check the url variables in such situations, when the user meddles with the URL vars and make sure the page does not error out. Similarly with the form fields. I am using the regexreplace like below to clean up the form fields before processing.

```
<cfset srchvar = ReReplace(srchvar,"\b(\w)","\u\1","ALL") />
<cfset srchvar = REReplace(srchvar,"[^0-9A-Za-z ]","","all") />
```

Is there any other checks that need to be applied?

Comment: Checks that have to be applied depend on what you are looking to accomplish.  Also, you can never guarantee that a page won't throw an error.  You might want to look at global error handling.  Also, replacing user input as opposed to reporting bad data to the user is not necessarily a good idea.

Comment: For an overall better understanding of programming with security in mind, read this excellent document by Pete Freitag - [ColdFusion Developer Security Guide](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf11/cfml-developer-security-guide.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I check the url variables in such situations, when the user
>   meddles with the URL vars and make sure the page does not error out?

```
<cfif !isValid('integer',URL.id)>
    <!--- Gracefully handle the error here --->
</cfif>
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fb9.html

> Is there any other checks that need to be applied.

I typically try to validate all data before I throw it in a database or use it. I use `isValid` to check datatypes, check or trim strings that may be too long, validate the existence of data when I don't accept NULLs. That way, my database doesn't have to throw the error upon insert, but rather I can catch it before that step.

Comment: Be careful validating dates.  ColdFusion is pretty generous on this topic.

Comment: .. and not just with dates:  [Why isValid(“integer”,“1,5”) = YES?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535979/why-isvalidinteger-1-5-yes).

Comment: @Leigh very true. I've been burnt by some validation logic in the past. But as long as you handle errors gracefully it does ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess your integer is too big for the type of database / driver you're using.  If you're using JDBC:

> The JDBC type INTEGER represents a 32-bit signed integer value ranging between -2147483648 and 2147483647.